# scanf in a while loop reads on first iteration only

Tags: c, scanf

NOTE: Please notice this is not a duplicate of [Why is scanf() causing infinite loop in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013) , I've already seen that question but the issue there is that he checks for `==0` instead of `!=EOF`. Also, his problem is different, the "infinite loop" there still waits for user input, it just does not exit.

I have the following while loop:

```
while ((read = scanf(" (%d,%d)\n", &src, &dst)) != EOF) {
                if(read != 2 ||
                         src >= N || src < 0 ||
                         dst >= N || dst < 0) {
                        printf("invalid input, should be (N,N)");
                } else
                        matrix[src][dst] = 1;
        }
```

The intention of which is to read input in the format (int,int), to stop reading when EOF is read, and to try again if an invalid input is received.

The probelm is, that scanf works only for the first iteration, after that there is an infinite loop. The program does not wait for user input, it just keeps assuming that the last input is the same.

`read`, `src`, and `dst` are of type `int`.

I have looked at similar questions, but they seem to fail for checking if scanf returns 0 instead of checking for `EOF`, and the answers tells them to switch to `EOF`.

Comment: remove `\n` from the `scanf`

Comment: @user3121023 , that's no good, it will stop recieving input after an invalid input.

Comment: @CoolGuy I actually started without `\n`, had the same problem. I added it because I seen a recomondation to it from another question. And to your second question, any input - valid or invalid - replicates the issue.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , see my previous comment (my response to CoolGuy)

Comment: @Tom , Try `int c;while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);` in the body of the `if`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is scanf() causing infinite loop in this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code)

Comment: @sashoalm , not a duplicate. I've already seen that question. his issue was that he checked `== 0` instead of `!=EOF`

Comment: @CoolGuy , in your suggestion, where should I read the input to `src` and `dst` ?

Comment: @Tom , Just add `int c;while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);` just after `printf("invalid input, should be (N,N)");`

Comment: Does "(%d,%d)\n" without a leading space work?

Comment: @CoolGuy , this does change something, but causes a weird bahaviour. it gets the valid input, but does not execute anything in the loop until it gets some kind of invalid input.

Comment: @CoolGuy , this is what I have now: http://pastebin.com/D6h01tzm . But it produces that odd behaviour I was talking about

Comment: @CoolGuy - your solution was spot on! I only needed to remove the `\n` from my `scanf` after that. If you phrase that as an answer I will accept it. (it might also help future generations). thanks

Comment: @Tom, EOF normally is defined as -1, scanf, when unable to parse any input field, returns 0.  It will never get to -1 on end of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
int c;
while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

at the end of the `while` loop in order to clear/flush the standard input stream(`stdin`). Why? The answer can be seen below:

The `scanf` with the format string(`" (%d,%d)\n"`) you have requires the user to type

1. An opening bracket(`(`)
2. A number(For the first `%d`)
3. A comma(`,`)
4. A number(For the last `%d`)

The space(First character of the format string of your `scanf`) and the newline character(`\n` which is the last character of the format string of your `scanf`) are considered to be [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). Lets see what the C11 standard has to say about whitespace characters in the format string of `fscanf`(Yes. I said `fscanf` because it is equivalent to `scanf` when the first argument is `stdin`):

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails

So, all whitespace characters skips/discards all whitespace characters, if any, until the first non-whitespace character as seen in the quote above. This means that the space at the start of the format string of your `scanf` cleans all leading whitespace until the first non-whitespace character and the `\n` character does the same.

When you enter the right data as per the format string in the `scanf`, the execution of the `scanf` does not end. This is because the `\n` hadn't found a non-whitespace character in the `stdin` and will stop scanning only when it finds one. So, you have to remove it.

The next problem lies when the user types something else which is not as per the format string of the `scanf`. When this happens, `scanf` fails and returns. The rest of the data which caused the `scanf` to fail prevails in the `stdin`. This character is seen by the `scanf` when it is called the next time. This can also make the `scanf` fail. This causes an infinite loop.

To fix it, you have to clean/clear/flush the `stdin` in each iteration of the `while` loop using the method shown above.

Answer (score -1):

`scanf` prompts the user for some input. Assuming the user does what's expected of them, they will type some digits, and they will hit the enter key.

The digits will be stored in the input buffer, but so will a newline character, which was added by the fact that they hit the enter key.

`scanf` will parse the digits to produce an integer, which it stores in the `src` variable. It stops at the newline character, which remains in the input buffer.

Later, second scanf which looks for a newline character in the input buffer. It finds one immediately, so it doesn't need to prompt the user for any more input.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my issue. Do you have a suggestion of what might fix it?

Comment: Can you share the entire code plz, adding a space after `(%d ,%d )` may help but need to verify

Comment: @yanivx , `%d` does **not** read `\n`. It skips it. and "*Assuming the user does what's expected of them, they will type some digits, and they will hit the enter key.*" is wrong. The `scanf` in the OP's question has brackets and a comma. These need to be typed too

Comment: @CoolGuy agreed but 2 consecutive `scanf` or `getline` leads to this issue where in the newline character fulfils the requirement of second `scanf` I will try the code and will get back

Comment: @Tom here is the answer to your ? you can use `%s` to  fix the problem which i have referred in my answer. A sample fix is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5453684/2959769