# Getting two inputs in one line C

Tags: c

I'm trying to receive two user input in one line in a user defined function

```
Example
Enter values for x and y -> 1 2
where x = 1, y = 2
```

This is what I've tried but my second variable is not scanned. Is there something wrong?

```
void getInput(int num, double* x, double* y)
{
printf("Enter values for x and y -> ", num);
scanf("%d", &*x);
scanf("%d", &*y);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanning Multiple inputs from one line using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453650/scanning-multiple-inputs-from-one-line-using-scanf)

Comment: Activate and read your compiler warnings

Answer (score 1):

For `scanf`:
`%lf` for double for pointer.
`%d` is for integer pointers.  `&*x` is the same as `x`

Since you don't do anything with `num` and it doesn't actually get used by your print statement, I just removed it.

```
void getInput(double* x, double* y)
{
    printf("Enter values for x and y -> ");
    scanf("%lf", x);
    scanf("%lf", y);
}
```

Comment: oh yes! thanks for reminding me. it worked:)